# 2sxc installation on DNN failed no app or content module

Tags: 2sxc

I'm using DNN 9.1.1 and am attempting to install 2sxc. I'm following the video, which is about as close as I could find for doing an install of this module. DNN 9 calls for dragging and dropping the module to be installed, so I did that, trying both versions from the 2sxc web site.

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STVxnkcHkZs&feature=youtu.be

The two versions I tried to install:
    2sic_2SexyContent_09.14.00_Install.zip
    2sic_2SexyContent_09.32.00_Install.zip

Both give me errors and here is a piece of the log:

```
Info Component installed successfully - Cleanup

Info Starting Installation - Cleanup

Info Component installed successfully - Cleanup

Failure ExceptionSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to 'C:\HostingSpaces\bridgeto\lta.bridgetoinfinity.com\public_html\Portals\_default\EventQueue\EventQueue.config' denied. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.Internal.InternalQuickIOCommon.NativeExceptionMapping(String path, Int32 errorCode)
 at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.QuickIOFile.OpenFileStream(QuickIOPathInfo pathInfo, FileAccess fileAccess, FileMode fileOption, FileShare shareMode, Int32 buffer)
 at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.QuickIOFile.OpenText(QuickIOPathInfo pathInfo)
 at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.FileSystemUtils.ReadFile(String filePath)
 at DotNetNuke.Services.EventQueue.Config.EventQueueConfiguration.GetConfig()
 at DotNetNuke.Services.EventQueue.EventQueueController.GetSubscribers(String eventName)
 at DotNetNuke.Services.EventQueue.EventQueueController.SendMessage(EventMessage message, String eventName)
 at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.ModuleInstaller.Commit()
 at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller.Commit()
 at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller.Install()
 at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer.InstallPackages(Boolean& clearClientCache)
 at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer.Install()

Info Deleted temporary install folder

EndJob Installation Failed
```

I'm not sure the process I'm using to install 2sxc is correct. For sure I need to get to the two modules the install includes, 'app' and 'container.'

Any suggestions, hints, etc. would be greatly appreciated. Thank You in advance...

:

Answer (score 0):

The error is very special - my guess is that your hosting environment has something special set up, probably preventing adding files to DNN or something. You should look at it with your hoster.